# How can I merge rows?

Tags: r

I'm completely new to this and struggling. I've downloaded a data set with multiple years and municipalities. Some of the municipalities have multiple names (because they have changed names over the years, some have merged, etc.) and I want to combine the municipalities to what they are called today. For example, "1212 x" and "4504 x," I just want to call them x. How can I do it?

I just need to sum up the values in the rows...

I tried to summarize, but the values are characters. I don't know. I had to download the Excel file, because CSV didn’t work.

dput:

```r
structure(list(arbeidsstedskommune = c("4601 Bergen", NA, NA,
NA, NA, NA), bostedskommune = c("4629 Modalen", "4631 Alver",
"4632 Austrheim", "4634 Masfjorden", "1252 Modalen (1910-2019)",
"1256 Meland (1924-2019)"), `2002` = c("0", "0", "0", "0", "0",
"0"), `2012` = c("0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"), `2022` = c("12",
"4171", "177", "90", "0", "0")), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df",
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

As you can see, I want f.i. "4629 Modalen" and "1252 Modalen (1910-2019)" to be the same "arbeidsstedskommune". I don’t know if I should mutate them somehow.

Example dataset:

Now:

```
a       b
2x      100
y.      50
4x      20
17y     NA
```

I want them like this:

```
a       b
x       120
y       50
```

Comment: Please run `dput(head(mydataframe))` where `mydataframe` is the object name of your data, and provide the output as part of your question.

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: So 4629 Modalen and 1252 Modalen belong to 4601 Bergen arbeidsstedskommune?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe some `tidyr` functions bring you into the right directions:

```
df |> 
 separate(bostedskommune, into = c("number", "name", "second_number"),
                  sep = " ") |> 
  group_by(name) |> 
  fill(arbeidsstedskommune) |> 
  pivot_longer(cols = `2002`:`2022`, names_to = "year", values_to = "value") |> 
  group_by(name, arbeidsstedskommune) |> 
  summarise(sum = sum(as.numeric(value)), .groups = "drop")
```

**Result**:

```
  name       arbeidsstedskommune   sum
  <chr>      <chr>               <dbl>
1 Alver      NA                   4171
2 Austrheim  NA                    177
3 Masfjorden NA                     90
4 Meland     NA                      0
5 Modalen    4601 Bergen            12
```